# Can't seem to find the source of my KeyError

Tags: python

I'm currently doing a leetcode question, and I feel as though my logic is fairly solid, but I am getting a `KeyError: 'B'` error on the line that says `if window_frequency[lefty] == 1:`
and cannot seem to figure it out. Does anyone have any ideas?

Also the purpose of the code is to find the minimum substring of string s that contains all the letters of the second inputted string (aka string t)

code:

```py
def minWindow(s, t):
    """
    :type s: str
    :type t: str
    :rtype: str
    """
    # dictionary of character frequencies

    # everytime we move the right pointer, we check if the letter frequency is a subset of the
    # window frequency dictionary, if it is, we set window_valid to true.

    # when the window is no longer valid, we increase move it, editing the frequencies of the             #window

    letter_frequency = {}
    window_frequency = {}
    left = 0
    current_result = ""
    result = ""

    # fill dictionary for letter frequency for t
    for each in t:
        if each not in letter_frequency:
            letter_frequency[each] = 1
        else:
            letter_frequency[each] += 1

    for right in range(len(s)):
        letter = s[right]
        # adding to frequency
        if letter not in window_frequency:
            window_frequency[letter] = 1
        else:
            window_frequency[letter] += 1

        # setting the result value if the window is valid

        window_valid = all(letter_frequency.get(key, None) == val for key, val in window_frequency.items())
        while window_valid == True:
            current_result = s[left:right]
            if len(result) == 0:
                result = current_result
            elif (len(current_result) < len(result)):
                result = current_result

            # now we decrease the size of the window till it is no longer valid
            lefty = s[left]
            if window_frequency[lefty] == 1:
                del window_frequency[lefty]
            else:
                window_frequency[lefty] -= 1
            left += 1


    return result



print(minWindow("ABAABANCHQR", "ABC"))
```

Comment: Please add the error stacktrace to the question.

Comment: You delete entries from the dictionary with `del window_frequency[lefty]`. If the same value of `lefty` comes later, you'll get an error.

Comment: Add print statements to the function so you can see how `window_frequency` is changing.

Comment: `while window_valid == True:` is an infinite loop, since you never reassign `window_valid`. That might be related to the problem, if it keeps looping when it shouldn't.

Comment: Use `collections.Counter`. For example, `letter_frequency = collections.Counter(t)`. The less code you have to write, the fewer places bugs have to hide.